# Passing arguments through a class in python

Tags: python

I have to call the "accelerate" method 5 times and display it's output after each iteration. The same must be done with the "brake" method. I have all of this written, but I'm at a loss in where to even begin to call the method in the main function to achieve my desired goal. Any help is greatly appreciated!! I'm in Python 3.3

```
class Car:

    def __init__(self):
        self.__year_model = 0
        self.__make = ''
        self.__speed = 0

    def set_year_model(self, year):
        self.__year_model = year

    def set_make(self, make):
        self.__make = make

    def set_speed(self, speed):
        self.__speed = speed

    def accelerate(self):
        return self.__speed + 5

    def brake(self):
        return self.__speed - 5

    def get_year_model(self):
        return self.__year_model

    def get_make(self):
        return self.__make

    def get_speed(self):
        return self.__speed

def main():

    mycar = Car()

    year = input('Enter the year of the vehicle: ')
    make = input('Enter the make of the vehicle: ')
    speed = input("Enter the vehicle's current speed: ")

    mycar.set_year_model(year)
    mycar.set_make(make)
    mycar.set_speed(speed)


    accel = mycar.accelerate()
    brake = mycar.brake()

main()
```

Comment: Is this homework? Why are they having you use name mangling? That's really confusing for new programmers to deal with...

Comment: Assignment yes... and yes... the whole transfering across everything has me all kinds of confused. No idea why it's done... all I know is what I'm supposed to give.I'm told that's the life of a programer though.

Comment: That's the life of a code monkey. You don't have to choose that life! Consider that further along your career (but for now, learn the basics.)

Answer (score 1):

This would be solved by a simple looping structure. In your main method, try:

```
for item in range(0,5):
  accel = mycar.accelerate()
  print(accel)
```

Edit: Please note that this is probably not the best way to do this, but the first way that came to mind. In regards to the int/str conversion, you might just want to cast. I typically use Python 2.7.x and couldn't remember if you needed to cast to string for Python 3.0's print function.

Comment: Since when did `range[0,5]` become valid python?!

Comment: When I tried the for loop I continued to get an error stating that it can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly. I assumed this had something to do with the method turning something into an int or a str somewhere along the way?

Comment: @rs2ts You are correct of course. I will fix that now. Glory of typos in quick answers.

Answer (score 1):

Your `accelerate` code is wrong: the changed speed is never stored. It should be

```
def accelerate(self):
    self.__speed += 5
```

and similarly for `brake`.

---

**Edit:** getter and setter methods aren't really idiomatic Python. You probably want

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, year, make, speed=0):
        self.year = year
        self.make = make
        self.speed = speed

    def accelerate(self, amount=5):
        self.speed += amount

    def brake(self, amount=5):
        self.speed -= amount

def main():
    year  = input('Enter the year of the vehicle: ')
    make  = input('Enter the make of the vehicle: ')
    speed = input("Enter the vehicle's current speed: ")
    mycar = Car(year, make, int(speed))

    print("Accelerating:")
    for _ in range(5):
        mycar.accelerate()
        print(mycar.speed)

    print("Braking:")
    for _ in range(5):
        mycar.brake()
        print(mycar.speed)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

which gives

```
Enter the year of the vehicle: 1990
Enter the make of the vehicle: Corolla
Enter the vehicle's current speed: 20
Accelerating:
25
30
35
40
45
Braking:
40
35
30
25
20
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the use of `input()` will make `__speed` and the like be strings, so OP needs to convert to an `int`, e.g. `mycar.set_speed(int(speed))`.

Comment: Thank you for that. I was only barely getting to where that would have proven not good. I am surprised that "return" doesn't need to be before "sefl.__speed += 5" though... I thought that would have to be there.

Comment: @2rs2ts - That fixed that error yes. Thankyou. Now though it tells me that 'type' is no subscriptable... what does that even mean??

Comment: `Car.accelerate()` is the same thing as saying `Car.set_speed(Car.get_speed()+5)`. That's why you do not need a return. Your error... you probably copied `range[0,5]` from the other answer, right? I think you want `range(0,5)`.

Comment: Ah... ok. That makes sense now. Thank you for the help. Just have to figure out why I'm getting 10 "none" as output now.

Comment: Try `print(mycar.get_speed())`. Like `set_speed`, `accelerate` is a "mutator" method which changes the state of the object, but returns nothing. Hence the `None`. You want this behavior, though - because you should use the "accessor" method, `get_speed`, to get the internal state of the object.

Comment: The code up there make WAY more sense and is what I would have tried to write. But I can't pass anything after init but "self". Also... nice to know I'm being taught getters and setters are the norm and they aren't... wonderful. thanks all the same though. The code really helps.@2rs2ts - I'm not trying to access the speed at the end though. I want the accel and brake?

Comment: @user3534918 "getter" and "accessor" are basically the same thing; the same can be said of "setter" and "mutator." Now, what do you mean you want "the accel and brake?" I think what you want is to show the speed going up (and down) by 5 each time, and I've told you how you can do that (by using `get_speed`).

Comment: You're right with what I'm trying to get yes. But putting "get_speed" in there caused an error. I'm not really sure what in the world I'm doing wrong here. This convoluted argument passing and creation forno reason has me so bloody confused.

Comment: @user3534918 Here, take a look at this [demo](http://ideone.com/rvNySD) so you can see what I'm trying to describe. Hopefully it'll shed some light for you.

Comment: I get it now... I was assigning "accel" and "brake" twice, both in and outside my loops. Thank you again everyone!!